# Rails 4 Database Tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have to store details of different kinds of vendors like: hotels, restaurants, motels, etc. I am not sure of the types of vendors right now. All of them have different details associated to an extent.

The way to access them is the same. What I am planning to do is have a url parameter for the same something like:
localhost:3000/vendors/hotels/1
localhost:3000/vendors/restaurants/3

I am confused whether to use a single table or have 4 different tables for:
Vendors (to have a reference to all the types above).
Hotels (foreign key for vendors)
Restaurants (foreign key for vendors)
Motels (foreign key for vendors)

If I do it in 4 different tables then I will be checking for what kind of vendor is it in every controller action and in every view associated with it.

Should I split it in four different tables or keep everything in 1 table. Or is there any other efficient way to do it?

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: Oops, it got deleted unintentionally I guess. The question is:
Should I split it in four different tables or keep everything in 1 table. Or is there any other efficient way to do it?

Comment: I would user 4 tables for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a `Vendor` table and a `VendorType` table.  Then in your routes to can pass in the vendor_type into the url:

```
get "/vendor/:vendor_type/:id", to: "vendor#show"
```